# How to pass user id and password to Guacamole to login to remote desktop?

Tags: java, jsp, remote-desktop, rdp, guacamole

The following is the link to connect with remote desktop

```
https://rdptest.trddc.com:8443/guacamole
```

How could I pass credentials to log into that system through url?

I will use window.open(url) to connect with remote desktop in java script

Please suggest me some way to connect to remote desktop passing credentials..

please help me out..

Thanks in advace.

Comment: If you pass it through the url wouldn't you be exposing the password?

Comment: Please suggest me to some way to pass parameters, which i use to log into my project.. I wanted to reuse them.......

Comment: If you are using JSPs then just make a forum (ie your standard login page) and have him submit the data over a secure connection. Then you can store the data in the user's session.

Comment: We can't get the values through session... Because we are trying to access the session values from some other computer.